# How can oxygen production during photosynthesis be measured?

Tags: photosynthesis, experimental-design

I'm curious how people measure ***quantitatively*** photosynthetic rate in labs.

I've seen many qualitative examples with direct observations of bubbles forming in water due to photosynthetic output of aquatic plants.

The ways I have come up with are:

- to measure the CO<sub>2</sub> intake.
- to measure the O<sub>2</sub> output.
- to measure the amount of sugar produced.

The 3rd option seems most trivial, but I don't know how to measure the amount of CO<sub>2</sub> present in a container. With a reaction? Or with a measuring machine of some sort? What about O<sub>2</sub>?

Comment: Similar [post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20224/how-is-photosynthesis-observed)